# Getting error on AngularJS (controller not registered) using ocLazyLoad + ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I've been trying to make ocLazyLoad work on my project, but I keep getting this Angular error

> Error: $controller:ctrlreg
>   A controller with this name is not registered
>
> The controller with the name 'eventoCtrl' is not registered.

---

NOTICE: I'm also using ui-router to define my app's states.

NOTICE #2: Any suggestion on other methods of using routes or lazy loads will also be apreciated

---

**app.js**

```
(function(){
angular
    .module('kulchr', [
      'ui.router',
      'oc.lazyLoad'
    ]);})();
```

**config.js**

```
angular
.module('kulchr')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('eventos', {
    url: '/eventos',
    views: {
      'top-menu-nav': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/top-menu-nav.html',
      },
      'main': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/eventos.html',
        controller: 'eventoCtrl as listaEvento',

        resolve: {
          eventoCtrl: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(
              {
                files: ['controller/listaEventoController.js'
                       ,'service/eventoService.js']
              });
          }
        }

      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

**controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('kulchr')
        .controller('eventoCtrl', ListaEventoController);

    ListaEventoController.$inject = ['servicoEvento'];

    function ListaEventoController(evento){
        var vm = this;

        var promise = evento.buscaDados();

        promise.then (function(response){
            vm.eventos = response.data;
        })

    }
})();
```

**service**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('kulchr')
        .service('servicoEvento', Evento);

    function Evento($http, $q) {
        var d = $q.defer();
        var self = this;

        $http.get('/mockup-data/eventos.json')
            .then(function (response){
                d.resolve(response);
            }, function(reason) {
                console.log("Motivo: " + reason.data +
                            "Status: " + reason.status +
                            " - " + reason.statusText);
                return $q.reject(reason);
            });


        self.buscaDados = function(){
            return d.promise;
        }
    }

})();
```

What am I missing here? I've reached the ui-router documentation but it just made more confused

BTW, Everything is working fine when adding the files directly on the index.html file using .

Comment: have you declared your service/

Comment: Yes, I did. I forgot to add it to the original post. I'll edit and add it now, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently what happening is, your `listaEventoController` is haven't goad loaded when `named view` is rendering. The reason being is `resolve` object has been used in wrong place. It doesn't work on named view level. It should taken out and keep it after `url`(flatten property) inside state definition object.

By taking `resolve` out `oc-lazyLoad` module will take care of downloading `listaEventoController` & `eventoService` file from server and would make download service register inside angular context and available to use inside angular application.

**Code**

```
$stateProvider
.state('eventos', {
    url: '/eventos',
    views: {
      'top-menu-nav': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/top-menu-nav.html',
      },
      'main': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/eventos.html',
        controller: 'eventoCtrl as listaEvento'
      }
    },
    //moved resolve out from "named view" object.
    resolve: {
       eventoCtrl: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
          return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                files: [
                  'controller/listaEventoController.js',
                  'service/eventoService.js'
                ]
             }
          );
       }
    }
})
```